ULx200x V.S. SN7546x
I would like some help understanding the difference between these two Darlington transistor arrays, and which one may be a better fit for my application.
I have a 5 VDC 500 mA max. PSU powering an FPGA in a controller which can switch 8x 5 V channels for use as external I/O control. Each I/O channel can switch 200 mA max.
I would like to use the FPGA to control external 24 VDC relays and 24 V 2 A solenoids. My current plan is to run the 5 V 200 mA I/O channels into a Darlington Array, which will control a 5 V Form A (SPST) relay that switches the output of an external 24 VDC PSU.
My question: it seems like I need a ULN2002A for my application, but I also found a SN75468 which seems to do the same thing. Is this just a TTL vs CMOS thing?
Finally, I was also investigating opto-isolators and solid state relays for this application. The opto-isolators seem to not be able to throw around enough current to reliably fire industrial relays, and SSRs seem more expensive than the DTA-relay combo. Is this generally true or am I missing some obvious/common component that would solve all of my problems?
I have attached an example circuit to show my plan (the circuit is missing some details for clarity)


I think the difference is just that the SN7546x can handle wider voltage ranges. There's no reason to use any middle-man circuitry either. You could even control the solenoids directly if you use high side driver MOSFET solutions, which will radically cut down your BoM - at the expense of "marrying" the vendor that has de facto monopoly on such drivers.

(In case you are leaning towards the arranged marriage, then this is what I'm talking about. Great parts, unreliably company. )

I should have mentioned that galvanic isolation is critical for this application, hence the desire to keep the 5V relay or optoisolator. My FPGA controller is close to 10 grand, so I would much rather swap fuses and a few burnt components from a short. The device you have linked is actually helpful for a different project so thank you!

Why exactly is it critical though? Some sort of motor controller? This looks like plain old on/off solenoids to me.

this is a modular industrial controller which could be used to interface with a wide range of I/Os. We might use one I/O to fire a valve solenoid, another to supply a relay, and two others as an interlock loop. We have had forklifts hit valve coils causing a short, which propagated to our old controller and cooked it. Hence the isolation need. I understand there are other more purpose built protections for this event, but right now I am keeping it as simple as possible.

Finally, as odd as it sounds, relays are easier for end users to understand, so we are trying to keep the controller away from complex electronics as we can. I know this might seem like a poor decision, why compromise functionality for user understanding? But we know from experience that repair techs who think they know what their doing will modify at will, so knowing this, we want to set these fools up for the best chance of success. It's one of those engineering vs the real world problems I've been dealing with with upper mgmt.

I work with very similar applications and there is rarely ever the need for isolation. Hence the "smart" in smart high side driver, these have all manner of overcurrent and reverse voltage protection built-in. If it needs to be "clown proof" then that's another story, of course. Socket mounted relays might be the way to go then indeed. Add lots of flyback and/or TVS as well.

@AustinFox your circuit will never work as shown even without the missing details.

Andy, could you please clarify, this comment is cryptic and unhelpful?

Why not a bog-standard N-channel MOSFET and switch each relay on the low side?

@AustinFox I think the comment from Andy is that the Darlington array is shown as switching the "high side" of the relay coils, rather than the "low side".

SN7546x is a higher voltage version of the ULN200x (100 V vs. 50 V), otherwise they're pretty much the same.
They are neither TTL nor CMOS, they are bipolar Darlington arrays.
Note that both the SN7546x and ULN200x are arrays of 7, not 8. If you want 8 you should look at the ULN280x series.
Also note that the last digit in the part number indicates differences in the input circuit to interface with different logic families, so you need to get the right one for your application.
